# how to return a value other than #f in racket

Tags: racket

I am really new at racket and I could not figure out how I can return -1 instead of #f

```scm
 (define numberList '(1 2 6 7))
```

Search a list of numbers for an element and return that place in the list (-1 if the number does not exist)

```scm
(define (searchElem list element)
  (for/or ([y list] 
           [i (in-naturals)] 
           #:when (equal? element y))
    i))

 (searchElem numberList 6)   ; returns 2
 (searchElem numberList 11)  ; returns #f
```

I need to return -1 when the number does not exist. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `or` to specify a default value:

```
(or (for/or ...) -1)
```